# Table Spacing with "setspace" and "etoolbox"

Tags: tables, etoolbox, setspace

I use the set spacing package, to avoid that tables are condensed I also use the etoolbox package to define the tabular environment. However, in one specific table the 1.5 spacing is too much and I would like to reduce it. I tried groups and array stretch but cannot really figure out how to overwrite the spacing for a single table? Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\onehalfspacing}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
       aa  & bb \\
       cc  & dd
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `setspace` for that. It's more convenient to redefine the value of `\arraystretch`, or if you prefer to have cells that look more vertically centred, load  the `cellspace` packge which defines minimal vertical spcinds at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you also load `siunitx`, or any letter you please with the `column=`  option).

Demo, in added horizontal lines to help better visualise:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{2pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{2pt}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[h]
{\onehalfspacing
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
\hline
       aa & bb \\
\hline
       cc & dd \\
\hline
    \end{tabular}}
\qquad
{ \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\hline
       aa & bb \\
\hline
       cc & dd \\
\hline
    \end{tabular}}
\qquad
    \begin{tabular}{Sc|Sc}
\hline
       aa & bb \\
\hline
       cc & dd \\
\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With a current latex you could add `\singlespacing` for the next use of the hook:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\onehalfspacing}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
       aa  & bb \\
       cc  & dd
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\AddToHookNext{env/tabular/begin}{\singlespacing}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
       aa  & bb \\
       cc  & dd
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
       aa  & bb \\
       cc  & dd
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Side remark: don't use [h] everywhere. If you are unlucky your tables don't fit and then they will pill up at the end of the document. See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020)